# MapReduce on Yarn:Control the mapper or reducer tasks running simultaneously?

Tags: concurrency, mapreduce, mapping, max, hadoop-yarn

My mapreduce-based hive sql  is running on Yarn and the hadoop version is 2.7.2 . What I want ,it to restrict the mapper tasks or reducer tasks **running simultaneously** when some hive sql is really big. I have tried following parameters ,but in fact they are not what I want:

```
mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum: The maximum number of reduce tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.

mapreduce.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum: The maximum number of map tasks that will be run simultaneously by a task tracker.
```

the above two parameters seems unavailable for my yarn cluster, because yarn has no concept of JobTracker,which is the concept of hadoop 1.x? And I have checked my applicatiion whose running mappers is above 20, but the mapreduce.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum value is just the default value `2`.

and then , I tried the following two parameters , also, they are not what I need:

```
mapreduce.job.maps: The default number of map tasks per job. Ignored when mapreduce.jobtracker.address is "local".

mapreduce.job.reduces: The default number of reduce tasks per job. Typically set to 99% of the cluster's reduce capacity, so that if a node fails the reduces can still be executed in a single wave. Ignored when mapreduce.jobtracker.address is "local".
```

`mapreduce.job.maps` is just a hint for how many splits will be created for mapping tasks , and `mapreduce.job.maps` define how many reducer will be generated.

But what I want to limit ,is how many mapper or reducer tasks was allowed to **run simultaneously for each application**?

In my below screenshot, a yarn application has at least 20+ mapper tasks running ,which cost too much cluster resource.I want to limit it to 10 at most.

[image]

So, what can I do?

Comment: In short, you want to enforce quotas in YARN. Look into Fair Scheduler / Capacity Scheduler documentation...

Comment: As you reply , parallelism degree of  MapReduce job on Yarn is just controlled by yarn .Yarn , as a resource scheduler , have no idea of what is running in its container, so , what I can do ,is just control the parallelism from the yarn scheduler aspectr(In fact I am using FairScheduler), nothing else?

Comment: _"parallelism degree"_ of the job is set by the execution framework (MapReduce, TEZ, Spark) based on input size and input fragmentation -- e.g. 3 files with a total of 5 HDFS blocks, and no "merge small files" options, mean 5 mappers (or 5 Spark partitions).

Comment: Again, what you are talking about is global _resource management_ of the cluster. That's what scheduler queues are about. Why don't you simply define a specific queue for that job, with specific quotas, and tell the job to request that queue at start-up?

Answer (score 1):

There may be several questions here. First of all to control the reducers for a particular job running at the same time of the mappers or before all of the mappers have completed you need to tweak: mapreduce.job.reduce.slowstart.completedmaps.

This parameter defaults to .8 which is 80%. This means when 80% of the mappers complete the reducers to start. If you want the reducers to wait until all of the mappers are complete then you need to set this to 1.

As for controlling the number of the mappers running at one time then you need to look at setting up either the fair scheduler or capacity scheduler.

Using one of the schedulers you can set minimums and maximums of resources for a queue where a job runs which will control how many containers (Mappers and Reducers are containers in Yarn) run at one time.

There is good information out there about both schedulers. 
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/FairScheduler.html

https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-yarn/hadoop-yarn-site/CapacityScheduler.html

Comment: As you reply , parallelism degree of  MapReduce job on Yarn is just controlled by yarn .Yarn , as a resource scheduler , have no idea of what is running in its container, so , what I can do ,is just control the parallelism from the yarn scheduler aspectr(In fact I am using FairScheduler), nothing else?

Comment: But what can I do to simply restrict the resource usage for single application , instead of a queue?

Comment: There are two schedulers. You could use the capacity and/or the fair scheduler. I would recommend researching both as they have quite a few options to tune. The links are above in my first post.